# Can you help me understand this php script

Tags: php

I'm a fairly newbie php coder, got this php code in a tutorial to create a randomly generated quote, but I don't fully understand the code

IN particular, I don't understand

a) line 4 -- where does the "rows" come from. Is that a name made up on the spot. Could it just as easily have been called "ferrari"

b) line 9 -- where does "storedtext" come from? is it just made up on the spot?

c) based on the code, do you have an idea what the database is supposed to look like. Would it just be a database called "text" with a table called "quotables" in it?

```
    <?  
    // 
    // count() gets the number of rows from database text-- 
    //it assigns a number to rowcount
 1   $rowcount = mysql_query("select count() as rows from text");

    // don't understand what exactly is happening here, where did "rows" come from
 2  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowcount))
 3   {
 4       $max = $row["rows"];
 5   }

    // Selects an item's index at random    
 6   $rand = rand(1,$max)-1;
    //there is a database table called "quotables?" taking one random row
 7   $result = mysql_query("select from quotables limit $rand, 1");

 8   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
//where does "storedText" come from?????
 9   $randomOutput = $row['storedText'];

 10   echo '<p>' . $randomOutput . '</p>';
 11   ?>
```

Comment: Please note that your code is logically incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) rows is the alias given to the count() function in the mysql query in line 1. If you changed rows in line one to ferrari then changed rows in line 4 to ferrari then it would still work.

B) stored text comes from the second mysql query on line 7. This will be the name of a column from within that table.

C) Based on the code you have given I can tell you that you have a database which I do not know the name of and that database has two tables one called `text` and the other `quotables` I can tell you that quotables has one column called `storedText`.

Answer (score 3):

> where does the "rows" come from?

It is a name assigned to a value in the SQL query `select count() as rows from text`.

> where does "storedtext" come from?

It seems to be the name of a field in the `quotables` table.

> based on the code, do you have an idea what the database is supposed to look like. Would it just be a database called "text" with a table called "quotables" in it?

No. We cannot say anything about the database name. But this database contains the tables `text` and `quotables` where the latter has at least the field `storedText`.

Answer (score 2):

a) Yes. 
b) It must be a column in the database. In line 7, it's pulling all columns in the database, but isn't specific about it's names
c) No, you could print_r($row) to see the table structure though (will print out the array, showing all columns). You should also have access to the db (to make this work, you'll need the db and tables set up), so however you mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() will tell you the name of the host/db.

Comment: With regards to your answer for a) the $row variable is made up on the spot however 'rows' is not, it corresponds to the alias in the mysql query.

Comment: Ah, yes, I misread the variable. I guess a case for renaming the variables to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

a) rows came from sql query `"select count() as rows from text"`

b) I think there "*" in line 7 because there is no column specified, so if * is there then its selecting all the columns in that table and "storedText" is one column in it

c) text,quotables both are tables

Comment: Except the query in lin 8 is wrong (does not contain column name_.

Answer (score 1):

a) `rows` comes from the SQL query:

```
$rowcount = mysql_query("select count() as rows from text");
```

It is the name given to the count() column.

b) `storedText` is a column in the `quotables` table, probably with the quote in it.

What the script does is, get a row count from the text table.
Get a random number in the range of 1 to $max.
Get the corresponding quote from the quotables table.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL doesn't tell us anything except that `quotables` is a table and `storedText` is a column in it. The names in strings show up in the SELECT statement and come into existance when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

"rows" come from mysql table. This is the name of column. For instance, if you have table with 2 columns, and one of them named like "price" you should use $var['price'] after using mysql_fetch_assoc to use it.
'storedText' the same.

Answer (score 0):

ANS - 1
  in while loop,  we have assigned value to $row...

ANS - 2

If you have looked code carefully, on line no 8, you have again assigned value to $row.
in line no 8 mysql_fetch_array($result) will fetch all the values for 1st row in array format.

there must be one column in "quotables" table named "storedText" so that it is coming in the $row['storedText'].

you should refer php manual toi understand mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc functions..

refer this url : http://be.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 is relevant to a)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowcount))
```

the `while`-construct will repeat as long as the expression inside the parentheses evaluates to a true-ish value. In PHP; an assignment is also an expression, which evaluates to the value being assigned, i.e. $row. Before each iteration, the function is executed and tries to retrieve the next row from the database. When it fails, it will return `false` instead of a row, which then in turn make the loop end, because the assignment-expression will evaluate to false, which is the terminating condition for the `while`-statement.

> b) line 9 -- where does "storedtext" come from? is it just made up on the spot?

It comes from a randomly fetched result from the database. It's the value of one column.

> c) based on the code, do you have an idea what the database is supposed to look like. Would it just be a database called "text" with a table called "quotables" in it?

We only know that the database has at least two tables `text` and `quotables`, the latter of which has at least one column `storedText`.

### What it does

It *tries* fetching a random quote. However, the logic is **not sound** and will most likely not work in all instances.

### Why is it wrong?

Basically, it assumed that for each row in `text`, there is exactly one entry in `quoteables`. If that was so, you would not need two tables in the first place. Because of this, I assume that quoteables can contain any number of rows, possibly even less, in which case you would sometimes not get a single result from the query. This would have your query fail and your script, because you try to access "false["storedText"] so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

A

```
$rowcount = mysql_query("select count() as rows from text");
 // the $rowcount is an array, the lines below get the values (that actually is just one)
 // and put into $max variable 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowcount))
 {
   $max = $row["rows"];
 }
```

B

```
 //get the text from database based on randon limit offet
 $result = mysql_query("select from quotables limit $rand, 1");

 //put the value returned into $row variable
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 //get the storedText (that is a table column name), and put the value into $randomOutput
 $randomOutput = $row['storedText'];
```

C:
 Based on code I can't afirm what is the database model.